# Passing a variable from a jade file to a React Component

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, pug

I am having trouble passing a variable from a .jade file to a react component.
Here is a section of my jade file:

`block content
  #example
    var user = '#{user}';
  span #{user.id}
  span #{user.displayName}`

And here is app.jsx, the react component that I would like to have access to the variable user.

```
var React = require('react');
var HelloWorld = require('./HelloWorld.jsx');
var $ = jQuery = require('../../libraries/jquery/dist/jquery');
var bootstrap = require('../../libraries/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap');

React.render(
    <HelloWorld/>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

I've tried logging `this.props.user` and `window.user` to the console from app.jsx but it is undefined. Ideally, I would like `this.props.user` in app.jsx to be the user that the jade file has access to. Then I would be able to pass that user variable into the HelloWorld component, for example. Perhaps there's a better way of doing this and I, being new to jade and react, would certainly appreciate that advice.

Comment: did you solve this problem if yes let me also know even i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used React, I'm not sure what React.render does or what its arguments are for so this might not be applicable.

To get a variable from server to client javascript try templating a json string into the html and loading it from the javascript. EJS handles quote escaping and I think Jade does too. For reference `content!= safeString` tells Jade to skip escaping, so does `content !{safeString}`.

```
- var user={id:1, displayName:'foo'}
#example
  meta(data-userJSON=JSON.stringify(user))
script(src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js")
script.
  var user = JSON.parse(
    $('#example meta').attr('data-userJSON')
  )
  console.log(user);
span #{user.id}
span #{user.displayName}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the DOM attributes manually before rendering, something like:

```
var node = document.getElementById('example')
var user = {
  id: node.children[0].textContent,
  displayName: node.children[1].textContent
}

React.render(<HelloWorld user={user} />, node)
```

But I would probably suggest you use JSON or ajax to fetch the data instead of parsing the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255517/passing-data-to-view-in-expressjs-reactjs) (I have tried to add a comment but it won't let me).

In your jade you will have:

`script.
    var user = (!{JSON.stringify(user)});`

Then, in React:

`React.render(
    <HelloWorld user={user} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);`

Be careful of passing data in the client you don't want anybody to see.

Answer (score 0):

Copying [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43191730/4347736) answer from a similar question:

"There is a library that works well with express (and any other view rendering node framework) called react-helper (https://github.com/tswayne/react-helper). It pretty much handles everything you need to do to render react components in your view and pass data to them from the server in any node framework. You just make an entry point (js file) for webpack (the lib has a cli that can generate your webpack config for you) and add a line to your controller and view and your component will render on that page. Passing data into your react components is really simple:

```
const component = reactHelper.renderComponent('MyComponent', {user: 
req.session.user || ''})
res.render('view-to-render', {component})
```

There is also express middleware for react-helper (https://github.com/tswayne/express-react-helper) that allows you to add context that is available to all views, which is convenient for user session data.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 req.reactHelperContext.user = req.session.user || '';
});
```

Then, all of your react components will have the user prop without having to manually add that logic to every controller action."

The library will render your component for you and store it into a variable that you can pass to jade, then in jade you just print the variable like you would a string.  That will handle the React.render for you, so you won't need that in your view anymore, or even the example div.  Your entry point will just "register" the HelloWorld component and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of doing the accepted answer:

1. Convert pug variable to json object

**file.pug**

```
script.
        var data = !{JSON.stringify(variable)}
```

2. Include variable in component

**file.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>It works {data.name} </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react-target"));
```